# Insert negative value into one sqlite column based on subtracting other values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having trouble writing a query that sets the value of a column called `improvement` to the difference between the integer values stored in  columns whose names are stored in the variables `latest` and `prev_list`.

My current query (with python string concatenation) is:

`'UPDATE players SET improvement=(' + latest + '-' + prev_list + ') WHERE ' + latest + ' IS NOT NULL AND ' + prev_list + 'IS NOT NULL AND ' + prev_list + ' != 0 '`

Now, if I change the query so that the values are added (`+`) instead of subtracted (`-`) inside of the parentheses the query works as expected, however when attempting to subtract them none of the `improvement` values are changes from the column default.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** As per a now-deleted comment - I tried adding brackets around the variable names, to no effect.

Comment: You missed quote before `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MichaelO. You're right, but that was a typo in the question rather than the original code :(

Comment: Print `latest` and `prev_list`, maybe one of them or both are `None`?

Comment: @MichaelO. Thank you for that! It turns out that I was setting the two variables to the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should change your query like below per my understanding

```
UPDATE players 
SET improvement = latest - prev_list 
WHERE latest IS NOT NULL
AND ( prev_list IS NOT NULL AND prev_list <> 0 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this has not solved the problem - the `improvement` column values all remain at their default after this query has been run.

Comment: @DTR, in that case the `where` clause doesn't matches any record. post some sample data

Comment: Thanks for the help - it turns out that i was setting both of the variables to the same column name, meaning that a-b always = 0.